# Get dominant terms in asymptotic expansion

Tags: simplifying-expressions, formatting, series-expansion, expression-manipulation

I'd like to find the dominant terms of an expression given the conditions $x,y >> 1$:

$c_0 y+\frac{y^2 \left(4 c_0^2 y - 12 c_1 c_2^2+y^2\right)}{24 x^2 \left(\text{c1}^2+\text{c2}^2+y\right)}$

Is there an easy way to do this?  I need the dominant terms for a given order O(x,y).  It would be helpful to get the "small" contribution as a separate output.  Thanks.

Comment: You can try `Series[(*expression here*), {x,Infinity,0},{y,Infinity,0}]`

Comment: thanks!  made an answer for future reference.

Comment: You really require more information regarding relative sizes of `x` vs. `y`.

Comment: ? I'm interested in your thoughts if you wish to clarify.  I consider them to increase parametrically on the same scale.

Comment: If they vary jointly e.g. `y=k*x` (or approximately equals) for some unspecified constant `k!=0` then you can just replace `y` with `k*x` and take the `Series`. If they vary in an unspecified way e.g. `y` could be on the order of `x^2` or `x^(1/2)` or `Exp[x]` then your asymptotic behavior will behave quite differently in different regions of the parametrized space.

Comment: Very good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both variables to the same, then evaluate as a series from infinity should work in most cases:

A straightforward example for some function `f = f(x,y)`:

```
Series[f/.{x->q,y->q},{q,Infinity,2}]
```

Of course this requires that both variables grow parametrically at the same rate.  This also allows you to take different limits: `x->1/q` for example if one of your variables limits toward zero.  A thanks to QuantumDot.